# Query to select only rows that only have a single status

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table with multiples of the same phone number, that I want to select only the numbers that have only ever had one status.

So out of this example...

```
  555-554-5444  NH
  555-555-5555  NH
  555-555-5555  DNC
  555-555-5555  INC
  555-554-5444  NH
  555-554-5444  NH
  555-555-5555  NH
```

I'd only want to return

```
  555-554-5444
```

Since its the only number that has ONLY NH as its status.

I know this is simple, and I feel really dumb for hacing to ask this... but I cant for the life of me think how I would do it.

Comment: Do you want to do this in sql or php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate by phone number and then select those that have only the status you are looking for:

```
select phonenumber
from table t
group by phonenumber
having min(status) = 'NH' and min(status) = max(status)
```

Comment: This works for a specific status. However, the question was about numbers that have only ever had one status, without specifying which status.

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni . . . both question are asked.  For the question about only one status, then the have class would be `min(status) = max(status)`.

Answer (score 0):

With pure mysql, you can use `group by` and `having count`

Code:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(phoneNumber) FROM table GROUP BY status HAVING COUNT = 1
```

It may have syntax error but its an approach

What is this query doing is grouping phone number by their status and counting em, so if your counter only found 1, thats your row

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT phone_number, COUNT(DISTINCT(status)) AS count_status
FROM tablename
GROUP BY phone_number
HAVING count_status = 1;
```